# Linux misreports process size with heap multi-mapping

Tags: linux

There is this issue in Linux when a process maps the same physical memory to multiple addresses at once ("heap multi-mapping").

For example, [Java's ZGC garbage collector](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/zgc-dev/2018-November/000540.html) does this.

When heap multi-mapping occurs, Linux (at least the versions I use) miscalculates (overreports) the resident process size. This affects top and all programs which query the OS for process sizes.

In effect, I have no more way of knowing how big a process actually is.

This screenshot is what top shows for a ZGC-enabled Java program with <<200 MB of Java objects. So in reality, the process is around 500 MB, not several GB.

[image]

So, to get to the question: Does anyone know a Linux version (or patch or tool) that can correctly report process sizes in this case?

Edit: [I now made my own little tool](https://github.com/stefan-reich/LinuxProcessSizeDetector) specifically for the ZGC use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask the kernel about how the process uses memory (`/proc/PID/smaps`) and then do the math based on the reported Shared and Private memory. The shared memory must only be counted once.

Below is some code that parses smaps and sums up the various types of memory usage for a list of pids. The unique set size (uss) memory is the private memory of the process, and might give a better idea about how much memory the process actually uses. Ultimately it becomes a question of how you would like to factor the shared memory into the equation.

> ```
> rss = '.+?Rss:\s+(\d+)'
> pss = '.+?Pss:\s+(\d+)'
> shared_clean = '.+?Shared_Clean:\s+(\d+)'
> shared_dirty = '.+?Shared_Dirty:\s+(\d+)'
> priv_clean = '.+?Private_Clean:\s+(\d+)'
> priv_dirty = '.+?Private_Dirty:\s+(\d+)'
> MEM_REGEXP = /#{rss}#{pss}#{shared_clean}#{shared_dirty}#{priv_clean}#{priv_dirty}/m
>
> def self.get_memory_map( pids)
>
>     memory_map = {}
>     #memory_map[ :pids_searched] = pids
>     memory_map[ :pids_found] = {}
>     memory_map[ :rss] = 0
>     memory_map[ :pss] = 0
>     memory_map[ :shared_clean] = 0
>     memory_map[ :shared_dirty] = 0
>     memory_map[ :rss_shared] = 0
>     memory_map[ :priv_clean] = 0
>     memory_map[ :priv_dirty] = 0
>     memory_map[ :uss] = 0
>
>     pids.each do |pid|
>         begin
>             # We don't want to see any "/proc/9723: No such file or directory" messages in stderr
>             lines = nil
>             Util.silently { lines = File.read( "/proc/#{pid}/smaps") }
>         rescue
>             lines = nil
>         end
>         if lines
>             lines.scan(MEM_REGEXP) do |rss,pss,shared_clean,shared_dirty,priv_clean,priv_dirty|
>                 memory_map[ :pids_found][pid] = true
>                 memory_map[ :rss] += rss.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :pss] += pss.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :shared_clean] += shared_clean.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :shared_dirty] += shared_dirty.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :rss_shared] += shared_clean.to_i + shared_dirty.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :priv_clean] += priv_clean.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :priv_dirty] += priv_dirty.to_i
>                 memory_map[ :uss] += priv_clean.to_i + priv_dirty.to_i
>             end
>         end
>     end
>     memory_map[ :pids_found] = memory_map[ :pids_found].keys
>     return memory_map
> end
> ```

Comment: Interesting. So something like this tool? https://github.com/craig08/parse_smaps

Comment: Yes something like that, if your process has children, you could use pstree -pn to get the child PIDs and then add recursively.

Comment: No children... :)

Comment: I still have to figure out how to exactly do the math here.

Comment: Oh, you added Ruby code. I'll have to figure out how to use it, one sec

Comment: I get this from your tool: rss=2580020, pss=1189931, rss_shared=2098564. Thus rss_shared - rss = ~500 MB which sounds very reasonable. (Or is that the wrong subtraction to perform?) The only remaining confusing point then is that rss_shared itself seems unrealistically high. top reports 3.1 GB used on the whole machine, and there are Chrome processes etc. Pretty sure those don't fit into the remaining 600 MB. Any further ideas? Thanks a lot for your effort!